# use Hash to check if an array has duplicate values in C++ in O(n)

Tags: hash

I did some research and found that this can be done in O(n) using Hash. But I am not sure about the specific algorithm. SOS. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can check if arr contains duplicates using the hash map in C++.
Below is function for that.

```
bool check(int arr[],int n){
    unordered_map<int,int> m1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(m1.find(arr[i])!=m1.end()) return true;
        else m1[arr[i]]=1;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Find in the unordered map (Hash Map) in C++ works in O(1)